# json_decode returning null on post request

Tags: php, json, post, file-get-contents

I have code that has been working for 5 years that broken recently possibly in connection with upgrading from php5 to php7. Have followed advice posted in similar threads and it continues to not work. I have an HTML file that only contains the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="incoming.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In the incoming.php I'm doing this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "DATA: " . $str . "<br>";
$json = utf8_encode($str);
echo "UTF8: " . $json . "<br>";
$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($data);
```

which produces the following output:

```
7.4.15
DATA: a=1&b=2
UTF8: a=1&b=2
NULL
```

I'm wondering where else I can look to try to figure out what might be going wrong.

Comment: That's an html query string, not a json string.

Comment: You can get the data from $_POST in the normal way. There's no JSON in what you've shown and no code which would generate any. Did you omit to show us some JavaScript or something? It's unclear how this could ever have worked or how a php upgrade could have caused this

Comment: Possible info of interest here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635158/file-get-contentsphp-input-not-working

Comment: @aynber according to geeksforgeeks, json_decode can handle the results of file_get_contents https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/

Comment: @ADyson getting data from $_POST instead of file_get_contents yields the same results for me

Comment: @Kinglish Thanks for the reference, I saw and ran through these steps on this same article prior to posting.

Comment: What precisely did you do with the $_POST data, to get the exact same result as you showed above? E.g. as I'm sure you know, you should be able to write `echo $_POST["a"];` and it would output `1`.

Comment: @ADyson i'm still not totally sure what's happening here, but if I post from an HTML form it behaves as above and is unable to decode the html query string, but if I post from an ajax request it correctly decodes the posted json data... but in either case, $_POST['whatever'] is able to correctly retrieve the variables. Is there a fundamental difference between what the PHP sees when it gets a post via AJAX vs an HTML form?

Comment: No there isn't, unless the AJAX code specifically sends the data in a different format. A HTML form always sends the data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format (unless you specify enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag, in which case it sends the data in multipart/form-data format). Whereas an AJAX call can send the data in any format of your choosing. It might be useful for us to see what AJAX code you're using which is enabling it to succeed.

Comment: `in either case, $_POST['whatever'] is able to correctly retrieve the variables`...then you don't really have a problem, as far as I can see. Just get the data from $_POST